# Parse json array String in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json String as follows.

```
"requestParams": [
        "SupplierId": 15357,
              "displayGsId": 5,
        "supplierName": "SUPPLIER1",
        "displayRequestId": 1
  ]
```

I am trying to parse it using Jackson 2. I know that it is an array and it maps to java.util.List in Java but, what about the elements in it. which object does it match to in java  and how should i retrieve all those elements in array. Does each element maps to HashMap?

Comment: What you have there is not valid JSON.

Comment: If you wrap the whole thing in `{}` then you'll have an object with a single array field `requestParams`. If you lose the `requestParams` label you'll have an array. As it stands, it's not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the input, so it becomes [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "requestParams": [
        {
            "zycusSupplierId": 15357,
            "displayGsId": 5,
            "supplierName": "MONASH_SUPPLIER1",
            "displayRequestId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```